# dataTable chama um dialog para edição, mas a edição não é efetivada. (prime faces 5.1)

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

Tenho uma aplicação WEB com primefaces 5.1 de um datatable chamo um dialog para edição, mas a edição não é efetivada.

Vou descrever com imagens e ao final posto o xHtml completo.

Tenho um p:datatable onde criei um botão para edição. Esse botão chama um dialog onde pretendo fazer a edição.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O dialog de edição é composto por 6 p:inputText e um dataTable editavel por celula.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando faço a edição tanto no dataTable como do inputText ao confirmar o valor não é atualizado.

No caso do inputText quando chamo o evento do botão gravar ele continua com o valor original.

No caso do dataTable quando o foco sai da edição volta o valor original mas se volto o foco na edição o valor continua lá ( veja sequencia de imagens ).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Notem que na penúltima figura digito o valor 55 na coluna "Qtd Pas Comum", quando saio da edição volta ao valor antigo "3" (veja ultima figura ), mas se entro para editar novamente o 55 esta lá.

E no todo, o objeto composicaoTASelecionada que contem os inputText e o List utilizado no dataTable do Dialog, que é o objeto alvo do botão editar, também não é atualizado no MB quando chamo o evento do botão gravar.

Até o momento não estou tendando persistir os dados estou tentando tratar o objeto em memoria.

Meu managedBean esta como @ViewScoped

**Template**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" >

<h:head>
    <title>
        <ui:insert name="titulo">Page Title</ui:insert>
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/estilo.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../resources/css/estilo.css"/>

</h:head>

<h:body >
    <h:form id="fPrincipal">    

        <p:layout fullPage="true" >

            <p:layoutUnit position="north" size="100" resizable="true" closable="false" collapsible="true" id="cabecalho">
                <ui:insert name="cabecalho">

                    <div class="alvCabecalho">
                        <p:graphicImage name="img/logo_branca.png" style="padding : 10px;height: 30px;width: 187px;" /> 
                        <h:outputLabel value="Sistema Complementar Alvorada" styleClass="outputLabel labelTitulo"/>
                    </div> 

                </ui:insert>
            </p:layoutUnit>

            <p:layoutUnit position="south" size="60" resizable="true" closable="false" collapsible="false" id="rodape">

                <ui:insert name="rodape">
                    <div class="alvRodape" >

                        <h:panelGrid cellpadding="50" columns="3" >

                            <p:commandLink id="fechar" rendered="#{sessionMB.btFechar}"
                                        action="#{sessionMB.fecharSessao}" 
                                        style="padding:00px; margin:00px;  height: 100%; width: 100px;" ajax="false">
                                    <p:graphicImage  rendered="#{sessionMB.btFechar}" name="img/botaoSair.png" style="padding : 5px;height: 30px;width: 30px;"/>
                            </p:commandLink>

                            <h:outputLabel value="Usuario : #{sessionMB.usuario}" styleClass="outputLabel labelRotape" rendered="#{sessionMB.btFechar}"/>

                        </h:panelGrid>

                    </div>
                </ui:insert>

            </p:layoutUnit>

            <p:layoutUnit position="west" size="250" resizable="true" closable="false" collapsible="true" id="menu" rendered="#{render_west}">
                <ui:insert name="menu">menu</ui:insert>
            </p:layoutUnit>

            <p:layoutUnit position="east" size="250" header="Parametros" resizable="true"  closable="false" collapsible="true" effect="drop" rendered="#{render_east}" id="mensagem">
                <ui:insert name="mensagem">Mensagens</ui:insert>
            </p:layoutUnit>

            <p:layoutUnit  position="center" id="corpo">
                <ui:insert name="corpo">
                    <p:graphicImage  rendered="#{sessionMB.btFechar}" name="img/logoFundoAzul.png" styleClass="fundoAlvodara" style="opacity:0.65;position:relative;left:33%;top:50%;"/>

                    <!-- <img src="../resources/img/logoFundoAzul.png" class="fundoAlvodada" />  -->

                </ui:insert>
            </p:layoutUnit>

        </p:layout>

    </h:form>           

</h:body>
```

**Pagina da aplicação utilizando o template acima.**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" > 

     <h:outputStylesheet name="/resources/css/estilo.css" library="css" />              

      <ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/templates/t_estrutural.xhtml">

            <ui:param name="render_east" value="true" />        
            <ui:param name="render_west" value="false" />
            <ui:param name="headerTitulo" value="Parametros" />

            <ui:define name="titulo">Calcula TA</ui:define>

            <ui:define name="mensagem">

                    <h:panelGrid columns="1">
                        <p:button id="btHome" outcome="principal" value="Home" icon="ui-icon-home" styleClass="botao-parametro" />

                            <h:outputLabel value="Ano/Mes:" for="anoMes"/>
                            <p:inputMask disabled="#{TA_MB.ctrlEntrada}" id="anoMes" value="#{TA_MB.anoMes}" validatorMessage="Periodo invalido" mask="9999/99" >
                                <f:validateRegex pattern="20[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}" />
                            </p:inputMask>

                            <p:commandButton id="consulta" disabled="#{TA_MB.ctrlEntrada}" value="Busca movimento" 
                                     actionListener="#{TA_MB.buscarLinhas}" icon="ui-icon-bookmark"
                                     styleClass="botao-parametro" 
                                     update="anoMes consulta novarequisicao linhasTA calculoTA gravaTA"
                                     onstart="PF('iconeDeProcessamento').show()"
                                     onsuccess="PF('iconeDeProcessamento').hide()" />

                            <p:commandButton id="calculoTA" disabled="#{TA_MB.ctrlProcessamento}" value="Calcular TA" 
                                     actionListener="#{TA_MB.calcularTA}" icon="ui-icon-bookmark"
                                     styleClass="botao-parametro" 
                                     update="linhasTA"
                                     onstart="PF('iconeDeProcessamento').show()"
                                     onsuccess="PF('iconeDeProcessamento').hide()" />

                            <p:commandButton id="gravaTA" disabled="#{TA_MB.ctrlProcessamento}" value="Grava TA" 
                                     actionListener="#{TA_MB.gravarTA}" icon="ui-icon-disk"
                                     styleClass="botao-parametro" 
                                     update="linhasTA"
                                     onstart="PF('iconeDeProcessamento').show()"
                                     onsuccess="PF('iconeDeProcessamento').hide()">
                                     <p:confirm header="Confirma ?" message="Confirma gravação dos Dados?" icon="ui-icon-alert" />
                            </p:commandButton>                                           

                            <p:button id="novarequisicao" disabled="#{TA_MB.ctrlProcessamento}" value="Nova Consulta" styleClass="botao-parametro" icon="ui-icon-refresh" outcome="taCalculo"/>                                                                                         

                    </h:panelGrid>

            </ui:define>

            <ui:define name="corpo">

                    <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" showSummary="false" autoUpdate="true" closable="true" />

                    <p:dataTable id="linhasTA" var="linha" value="#{TA_MB.listagemDeLinha}" stickyHeader="false" expandedRow="false">

                        <f:facet name="header">
                               <h:outputText style="font-weight: bold" 
                                value="Valor Total da TA: #{formatadorMB.formataMoeda(TA_MB.valorTotalTA)} " />
                        </f:facet>

                        <p:column style="width:16px">
                            <p:rowToggler />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Linha"  style="width:5%" styleClass="colunaTexto">
                            <h:outputText value="#{linha.linha}" />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Ramal"  style="width:5%" styleClass="colunaTexto">
                            <h:outputText value="#{linha.ramal}" />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Descição"  styleClass="colunaTexto">
                            <h:outputText value="#{linha.origem.descricao} / #{linha.destino.descricao}"    />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Qtd Lug."  style="width:10%" styleClass="colunaNumerica">
                            <h:outputText value="#{linha.lugaresOferecidos}" >
                                <f:convertNumber pattern="#0" />
                            </h:outputText>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Qtd Comb." style="width:10%" styleClass="colunaNumerica">
                            <h:outputText value="#{linha.quantidadeDeCombustivel}" >
                                <f:convertNumber pattern="#0.00" />
                            </h:outputText>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Vg Norm." style="width:10%" styleClass="colunaNumerica">
                            <h:outputText value="#{linha.viagensNormais}" >
                                <f:convertNumber pattern="#0" />
                            </h:outputText>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Vg Ext." style="width:10%" styleClass="colunaNumerica">
                            <h:outputText value="#{linha.viagensExtras}">
                                <f:convertNumber pattern="#0" />
                            </h:outputText>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Qtd Gratuitos" style="width:10%" styleClass="colunaNumerica">
                            <h:outputText value="#{linha.quantidadeDeGratuitos}">
                                <f:convertNumber pattern="#0" />
                            </h:outputText>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Qtd Professores " style="width:10%" styleClass="colunaNumerica">
                            <h:outputText value="#{linha.quantidadeDeProfessores}">
                                <f:convertNumber pattern="#0" />
                            </h:outputText>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="TA" style="width:10%" styleClass="colunaNumerica">
                            <h:outputText value="#{linha.valorTA}" >
                                <f:convertNumber pattern="#0.00" />
                            </h:outputText>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column style="width:32px;text-align: center"> 
                            <p:commandButton update=":fPrincipal:editaLinha linhasTA seccaoTa" oncomplete="PF('editaLinhaDialog').show()" icon="ui-icon-pencil" title="Edita Linha" >
                                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{linha}" target="#{TA_MB.composicaoTASelecionada}"   />
                            </p:commandButton>
                        </p:column>

                        <p:rowExpansion>
                            <p:dataTable id="seccaoTa" var = "seccao" value="#{linha.seccoes}">
                                <p:column headerText="Origem"  style="width:10%" styleClass="colunaTexto">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{seccao.origem.id}" />
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column headerText="Destino"  style="width:10%" styleClass="colunaTexto">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{seccao.destino.id}" />
                                </p:column>

                                <p:column headerText="Descição"  styleClass="colunaTexto">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{seccao.origem.descricao} / #{seccao.destino.descricao}"    />
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column headerText="Data Inicio"  style="width:10%" styleClass="colunaTexto">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{seccao.dataInicio}" />
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column headerText="Data Final"  style="width:10%" styleClass="colunaTexto">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{seccao.dataFim}" />
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column headerText="Tarifa"  style="width:10%" styleClass="colunaTexto">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{seccao.tarifaTA}" >
                                        <f:convertNumber pattern="#0.00" />
                                    </h:outputText>
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column headerText="Qtd.Pas. Comum"  style="width:10%" styleClass="colunaTexto">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{seccao.quantidadeDePassagensComuns}" >
                                        <f:convertNumber pattern="#0" />
                                    </h:outputText>
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column headerText="Qtd.Pas. Estudante"  style="width:10%" styleClass="colunaTexto">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{seccao.quantidadeDePassagensEstudantes}" >
                                        <f:convertNumber pattern="#0" />
                                    </h:outputText>
                                </p:column>

                            </p:dataTable>
                        </p:rowExpansion>

                    </p:dataTable>


                    <!--  ***********************************  Dialogo do progresso   ************************************************* -->

                    <p:dialog widgetVar="iconeDeProcessamento" modal="true" draggable="false" closable="false" resizable="false" showHeader="true" appendTo="@(body)"
                            header="Aguarde... Buscando Dados" style="width:20%;height:20%" >
                        <p:graphicImage id="progressoGif"  value="../resources/img/loader_blue.gif" style="width:40%;height:40%; display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto"/>
                    </p:dialog>

                    <!--  ***********************************  Dialogo da Confirmação de Gravação ************************************************* -->
                    <p:confirmDialog global="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="explode">
                        <p:commandButton value="Não" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close" />
                        <p:commandButton value="Sim" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check" />
                    </p:confirmDialog>

                    <!--  ***********************************  Dialogo da Edicao  ************************************************* -->
                    <p:dialog widgetVar="editaLinhaDialog"     modal="true" header="Edicao de Linha"  showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" resizable="true" appendTo="@(body)" height="600" width="1200" >
                        <!-- <p:accordionPanel id="editaLinha" multiple="true"> -->
                         <p:outputPanel id="editaLinha" > 


                            <p:fieldset style="margin-bottom:5px"> 
                                <h:panelGrid id="pgFixo" columns="2">
                                    <h:outputText id="outLinha" value="Linha:"/>
                                    <p:inputText id="inLinha" label="Linha" value="#{TA_MB.composicaoTASelecionada.linha}" maxlength="4" size="5" disabled="true" />

                                    <h:outputText id="outRamal" value="Ramal:"/>
                                    <p:inputText id="inRamal" label="Ramal" value="#{TA_MB.composicaoTASelecionada.ramal}" maxlength="1" size="2" disabled="true"/>

                                    <h:outputText id="outDescricao" value="Descricao:"/>
                                    <p:inputText id="inDescricao" label="Descricao" value="#{TA_MB.composicaoTASelecionada.origem.descricao.trim()} / #{TA_MB.composicaoTASelecionada.destino.descricao.trim()}" 
                                       maxlength="150" size="60" disabled="true" />
                                </h:panelGrid>
                            </p:fieldset>

                            <h:panelGrid id="pgLinhaEditavel" columns="4" cellspacing="10">                                 
                                <h:outputText id="outQuantidadeDeLugares" value="Quantidade de Lugares:"/>
                                <p:inputText id="inQuantidadeDeLugares" label="QuantidadeDeLugares" value="#{TA_MB.composicaoTASelecionada.lugaresOferecidos}" maxlength="12" size="6" dir="ltr">
                                    <f:convertNumber pattern="#0" />
                                </p:inputText>

                                <h:outputText id="outQuantidadeDeCombustivel" value="Quantidade de Combustivel:"/>
                                <p:inputText mask="9999999" id="inQuantidadeDeCombustivel" label="QuantidadeDeCombustivel" value="#{TA_MB.composicaoTASelecionada.quantidadeDeCombustivel}" maxlength="12" size="6" dir="ltr">
                                    <f:convertNumber pattern="#0.00" />
                                </p:inputText>  

                                <h:outputText id="outQuantidadeDeViagensNormais" value="Quantidade de Viagens Normais:"/>
                                <p:inputText id="inQuantidadeDeViagensNormais" label="QuantidadeDeViagensNormais" value="#{TA_MB.composicaoTASelecionada.viagensNormais}" maxlength="12" size="6" dir="ltr" >
                                    <f:convertNumber pattern="#0" />
                                </p:inputText>

                                <h:outputText id="outQuantidadeDeViagensExtra" value="Quantidade de Viagens Extra:"/>
                                <p:inputText id="inQuantidadeDeViagensExtra" label="QuantidadeDeViagensExtra" value="#{TA_MB.composicaoTASelecionada.viagensExtras}" maxlength="12" size="6" dir="ltr" >
                                    <f:convertNumber pattern="#0" />
                                </p:inputText>

                                <h:outputText id="outQuantidadeDeGratuitos" value="Quantidade de Viagens Gratuitos:"/>
                                <p:inputText id="inQuantidadeDeGratuitos" label="QuantidadeDeGratuitos" value="#{TA_MB.composicaoTASelecionada.quantidadeDeGratuitos}" maxlength="12" size="6" dir="ltr" >
                                    <f:convertNumber pattern="#0" />
                                </p:inputText>

                                <h:outputText id="outQuantidadeDeProfessores" value="Quantidade de Viagens Professores:"/>
                                <p:inputText id="inQuantidadeDeProfessores" label="QuantidadeDeProfessores" value="#{TA_MB.composicaoTASelecionada.quantidadeDeProfessores}" maxlength="12" size="6" dir="ltr" >
                                    <f:convertNumber pattern="#0" />
                                </p:inputText>

                            </h:panelGrid>


                            <p:scrollPanel  style="width:100%;height:250px" >    
                                <p:dataTable id="itensLinha" var="itens" value="#{TA_MB.composicaoTASelecionada.seccoes}" editable="true" editMode="cell" >

                                    <p:ajax event="cellEdit" listener="#{TA_MB.onCellEditSeccao}" update=":fPrincipal:messages itensLinha" />

                                    <p:column headerText="Descição"  styleClass="colunaTexto">
                                        <h:outputText value="#{itens.origem.descricao} / #{itens.destino.descricao}"    />
                                    </p:column>
                                    <p:column headerText="Data Inicio"  style="width:10%" styleClass="colunaTexto">
                                        <h:outputText value="#{itens.dataInicio}" />
                                    </p:column>
                                    <p:column headerText="Data Final"  style="width:10%" styleClass="colunaTexto">
                                        <h:outputText value="#{itens.dataFim}" />
                                    </p:column>
                                    <p:column headerText="Qtd.Pas. Comum"  style="width:10%" styleClass="colunaTexto">
                                        <p:cellEditor>
                                                    <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{itens.quantidadeDePassagensComuns}" /></f:facet>
                                                    <f:facet name="input">
                                                        <p:inputText id="modelInput" value="#{itens.quantidadeDePassagensComuns}" style="width:90%"  >
                                                            <f:convertNumber pattern="#0" />
                                                        </p:inputText>  
                                                    </f:facet>
                                                </p:cellEditor>
                                    </p:column>
                                    <p:column headerText="Qtd.Pas. Estudante"  style="width:10%" styleClass="colunaTexto">
                                        <p:cellEditor>
                                            <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{itens.quantidadeDePassagensEstudantes}" /></f:facet>
                                            <f:facet name="input">
                                                <p:inputText value="#{itens.quantidadeDePassagensEstudantes}" >
                                                    <f:convertNumber pattern="#0" />
                                                </p:inputText>
                                            </f:facet>
                                        </p:cellEditor>     
                                    </p:column> 
                                </p:dataTable>
                            </p:scrollPanel>

                            <p:fieldset style="margin-bottom:1px"> 
                                <h:panelGrid id="rodapeEdicao" columns="1">
                                    <p:commandButton id="gravaEdicaoDaLinha" value="Grava"
                                         actionListener="#{TA_MB.gravaEdicaoDaLinha}" icon="ui-icon-disk"
                                         styleClass="botao-parametro"
                                         oncomplete="PF('editaLinhaDialog').hide();" />
                                </h:panelGrid>
                            </p:fieldset>

                        </p:outputPanel>    
                    </p:dialog>


            </ui:define>
      </ui:composition> 

</html>
```

**Meu ManagedBean**

```
package br.com.transportesalvorada.controller.mb;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;

import org.primefaces.context.RequestContext;
import org.primefaces.event.CellEditEvent;
import org.primefaces.event.FileUploadEvent;
import org.primefaces.model.UploadedFile;

import br.com.transportesalvorada.model.DAO.conexao.AlvoradaException;
import br.com.transportesalvorada.model.DAO.trafego.ComposicaoTADAO;
import br.com.transportesalvorada.model.DAO.trafego.LinhaTADAO;
import br.com.transportesalvorada.model.DAO.trafego.SeccaoTADAO;
import br.com.transportesalvorada.model.bean.trafego.ComposicaoTA;
import br.com.transportesalvorada.model.bean.trafego.DeterTA;
import br.com.transportesalvorada.model.bean.trafego.FactoryTA;
import br.com.transportesalvorada.model.bean.trafego.SeccaoTA;

@ManagedBean(name="TA_MB")
@ViewScoped
public class TA_MB {

    protected boolean ctrlEntrada        = false;
    protected boolean ctrlProcessamento  = true;

    private int quantidadeDeUpLoads = 0;
    private UploadedFile upLoadFiles;

    private String anoMes;
    private List<ComposicaoTA> listagemDeLinha;

    private ComposicaoTA composicaoTASelecionada;

//-------------------------------------- COMUM -----------------------------------------

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    quantidadeDeUpLoads = 0;
    listagemDeLinha = new ArrayList<ComposicaoTA>();
    composicaoTASelecionada = new ComposicaoTA();
}

public void setComposicaoTASelecionada(ComposicaoTA composicaoTASelecionada) {
    this.composicaoTASelecionada = composicaoTASelecionada;
}

public ComposicaoTA getComposicaoTASelecionada() {
    return composicaoTASelecionada;
}

public String getAnoMes() {
    return anoMes;
}

public void setAnoMes(String anoMes) {
    this.anoMes = anoMes;
}

public List<ComposicaoTA> getListagemDeLinha() {
    return listagemDeLinha;
}

public void setListagemDeLinha(List<ComposicaoTA> listagemDeLinha) {
    this.listagemDeLinha = listagemDeLinha;
}

public UploadedFile getUpLoadFiles() {
    return upLoadFiles;
}

public void setUpLoadFiles(UploadedFile upLoadFiles) {
    this.upLoadFiles = upLoadFiles;
}

public boolean isCtrlEntrada() {
    return ctrlEntrada;
}

public void setCtrlEntrada(boolean ctrlEntrada) {
    this.ctrlEntrada = ctrlEntrada;
}

public boolean isCtrlProcessamento() {
    return ctrlProcessamento;
}

public void setCtrlProcessamento(boolean ctrlProcessamento) {
    this.ctrlProcessamento = ctrlProcessamento;
}

public void processaTa(ActionEvent actionEvent){
    ctrlEntrada        = true;
    ctrlProcessamento  = false;
}

public float getValorTotalTA(){
    float retorno = 0f;
    for(ComposicaoTA linha : listagemDeLinha){
        retorno += linha.getValorTA();
    }
    return retorno;
}



//-------------------------------------- RECEBER ARQUIVO DETER -----------------------------------------

public void uploadArquivo(FileUploadEvent event){
    RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
    if(quantidadeDeUpLoads==0) 
        context.execute("PF('iconeDeProcessamento').show()");

    this.quantidadeDeUpLoads++;
    try {
        System.out.printf( "\n********************* entrei no upload  %s ",this.quantidadeDeUpLoads);
        recebeAraquivo(event.getFile().getInputstream(),event.getFile().getFileName());

        System.out.printf( "\n********************* Finalizei upload %s ",this.quantidadeDeUpLoads);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Erro no upload " + ex);
    }        

    this.quantidadeDeUpLoads-- ;

    if(this.quantidadeDeUpLoads==0){
        context.execute("PF('iconeDeProcessamento').hide()");
        /*
        try {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("principal.xhtml");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }*/
    }


}

private void recebeAraquivo(InputStream inputstreamDoAquivo, String nomeDoAquivo) {
    InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = null;         
    BufferedReader bufferedReader= null;    
    String line;
    List<DeterTA> listaDeter = new ArrayList<DeterTA>();
    try {
        inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputstreamDoAquivo);
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            DeterTA obj = new FactoryTA().getDeterTA(nomeDoAquivo,line);
            listaDeter.add(obj);
        }
        bufferedReader.close();
        String ok = (new FactoryTA().getDeterTA(nomeDoAquivo)).gravaDeterTA(listaDeter); 
        if(  ok.trim().length()>2 ){
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(ok));
            System.out.printf("\n   %s",ok);
        }   

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void fechar(String sequencia){
    System.out.printf("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ %s",sequencia);
}


//-------------------------------------- CALCULO TA -----------------------------------------

public void buscarLinhas(){
    this.listagemDeLinha.clear();
    this.listagemDeLinha = new ComposicaoTADAO().buscaLinhas( anoMes.replace("/", "") );
    ctrlEntrada        = true;
    ctrlProcessamento  = false;
}

public void calcularTA(){
    new ComposicaoTA().calcularTa(getListagemDeLinha());
}

public void onCellEditSeccao(CellEditEvent event) {

    Object oldValue = event.getOldValue();
    Object newValue = event.getNewValue();

    System.out.printf("------ Entrou no Evento old %s new %s ",oldValue,newValue);

    if(newValue != null && !newValue.equals(oldValue)) {
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Cell Changed", "Old: " + oldValue + ", New:" + newValue);
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
    }
}



public void gravarTA(){
    System.out.printf("\n ---------- Entrou no GravarTA() ---- : %s ",getListagemDeLinha().size());

}

public void gravaEdicaoDaLinha(){
    System.out.printf("\n ---------- Entrou no gravaEdicaoDaLinha() ---- : ");
    System.out.printf("\n --- Linha %s  %s %s ", this.getComposicaoTASelecionada().getLinha(),this.getComposicaoTASelecionada().getRamal(), this.composicaoTASelecionada.getLugaresOferecidos());

}


public void testeEvento(String msg){
    System.out.printf("\n entrou no %s ",msg);
}
```

}

Comment: Marcelo, bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! Sua pergunta está bem explicada, porém ainda não há detalhes suficientes para determinar o problema. **Primeiro**: quando vc diz que "o valor não é atualizado", o que isso realmente significa? Seu Managed Bean não é atualizado? O valor chega e é atualizado no BD, mas não é exibida novamente na tela? **Segundo**: vi que está usando um componente, mas não é possível saber se tem um `form` em algum lugar. Sem um formulário é possível exibir os dados, mas estes nunca serão submetidos de volta ao seu Bean. Verifique isso e tente detalhar mais o problema.

Comment: Ainda não estou persistindo os dados.
Primeiro vamos ao DataTable - Note que na penúltima figura digito o valor 55 na coluna "Qtd Pas Comum", quando saio da edição volta ao valor antigo "3" (veja ultima figura ), mas se entro para editar novamente o 55 esta lá.

E no todo, o objeto composicaoTASelecionada que é o objeto alvo do botão editar, também não é atualizado no MB quando chamo o evento do botão gravar.

Comment: O form esta no template - vou posta-lo para melhor compreensão.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depois de muito pesquisar, descobri o problema.
A propriedade appendTo do dialog estava como appendTo="@(body)", isso estava jogando os dados para o h:Body do xHtml e fora do h:form o que não estava submetendo os dados.

Mudando o appendTo="@(form)" o programa se comportou como desejado.

Aparentemente um conceito simples mas se não estiver bem compreendido pode complicar.

Espero que ajude quem enfrenta o mesmo problema.